# cumulative sum by group and under some condition in r

Tags: r

Within the group with the same `m1` and `n1`, I need to calculate cumulative sum of `x1`  if `x1` is not 0 and cumulative sum of `y1` if `y1` is not 0. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 d <- data.frame () 
    for ( m1 in 2: 3) { 
         for (n1 in 2: 3){ 
              for (x1 in 0: m1) { 
                   for (y1 in 0: n1) {                                                                                                         

                  d<-rbind(d, c(m1, n1, x1,y1)) 
    }}}}
```

so for `m1=2`, `n1=2`, the cumlative sum of `x1` should be 9 and sum of `y1` is 9, 
for  `m1=2`, `n1=3`, the cumlative sum of `x1` should be 12 and sum of `y1` is 18.

Comment: What should happen in the cases, which include different values in `m1` and `m2`?

Comment: For those of us who are not Svens, what do input and output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? (using `data.table`). And I think you want to sum all the elements, and not cumulatively sum and return all elements.

```
# after running your code, I had to rename it
names(d) <- c("m1", "n1", "x1", "y1")
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(d)
setkey(dt, m1, n1)
out <- dt[, list(s.x1=sum(x1), x.y1=sum(y1)),by="m1,n1"]
> out
#    m1 n1 s.x1 x.y1
# 1:  2  2    9    9
# 2:  2  3   12   18
# 3:  3  2   18   12
# 4:  3  3   24   24
```